# SQL joining like grouping List

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a couple of list that I want to group if a given field that represent the same is equals, and I was wondering if there is a way to doing in lambdas or streams

Suppose we have a list that have a container information

```
container1-> containerInfo
container2-> containerInfo
```

Then we have another list that represent the elements in the container and the container name

```
element1 -> container1 + elementInfo
element2 -> container1 + elementInfo
element3 -> container2 + elementInfo
element4 -> container2 + elementInfo
```

There is a way I can join by component both list given the conditions that, both are different classes and also I need certain info from both list, at the end I want to have something like this

```
Map<Integer,List<ContainetElementMap>> map;
```

Eg:

```
{containerId, {containerName,elements,extraInfo}}
{containerId, {containerName,elements,extraInfo}}
```

I know there is a groupBy and that could help but it is only working if both objects are the same type, I need something like when sql is doing a join between tables

Comment: What do your existing classes look like? What have you tried with `groupingBy`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. I used set instead of list and other point you need to filter out values without element from the map:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Elem>> m = containers.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Container::getId,
                        Collectors.flatMapping(
                                container -> elems.stream().filter(elem -> elem.containerId == container.id),
                                Collectors.toSet())
                 )
    );
```

This is Container class:

```
class Container {
    Integer id;

    public Container(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And Element:

```
class Elem {
    Integer id;
    Integer containerId;
    String name;

    public Elem(Integer id, Integer containerId, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.containerId = containerId;
        this.name = name;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I implemented as you mention and I think the method Collectors.flatMapping not exist, I changes to mapping but is throwing an error that it is return me a map of Integer, Set<Object> instead of Integer,Set<Elem>, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @jam, sorry forgot to mention I used Java 9, this is the new method in the Collectors.

Comment: There is a way of doing this in java 8?